# matplotlib set legend and plot lines properties through one function

Tags: matplotlib

I noticed that by calling plt.legend() before setting plot line properties, lines withing the legend box were not adjusted accordingly to the settings.
here is an example plot and a function used to set legend and plot line properties:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10), '-x', label = 'legend text')
ax.plot(2 * range(10))
leg = plt.legend(title = 'legend here')

def plotprop_adj(ax, leg, fs = 16, lw = 2, ms = 10)
    ltext = leg.get_texts()
    for item in ltext:
        item.set_fontsize(fs)
    for ln in ax.lines:
        ln.set_linewidth(lw)
        ln.set_markersize(ms)

plotprop_adj(ax, leg)  #  leaves lines in legend box with 
                       #+ different properties than the corresponding plots
```

Consequently I tried to manually set the line properties within the legend as following (add to plotprop_adj(...)):

```
def plotprop_adj(ax, leg, fs = 16, lw = 2, ms = 10)
    [...]
    leg_ln = leg.get_lines()
    for ln in leg_ln:
        ln.set_linewidth(lw)
        ln.set_markersize(ms)
```

as a result the lines withing the legend box have the right thickness, but the length is nearly half, and the marker size does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is a confirmed bug in matplotlib:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2035